# django 1.10 cycle to add hr tag every 4th element

Tags: html, django, django-templates, jinja2

I want to add an hr element every 4th child element in my html doc. This is what I have so far:

```
<div class="row blog-post">
    {% for obj in object_list %}
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                {% if obj.image %}
                    <img src="{{ obj.image.url }}" class="img-responsive"/>
                {% endif %}
                <div class="caption post-detail-item">
                    {% if obj.draft %}<h3>Staff only: <span style="color:red;">Draft</span></h3> {% endif %} {% if obj.publish > today %}<h3>Staff only: <span style="color:red;">Future Post</span></h3>{% endif %}
                    <h3><a href='{{ obj.get_absolute_url }}'>{{ obj.title }}</a><small> {{ obj.publish|timesince }}</small></h3>
                    {% if obj.user.get_full_name %}
                        <p>Author: {{ obj.user.get_full_name }}</p>
                    {% endif %}
                    {{ obj.get_markdown|truncatechars_html:350 }}
                    <p><a href="{{ obj.get_absolute_url }}" class="btn btn-primary" type="button">View</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    {% cycle "" "<div class='col-sm-12'><hr/></div></div><div></div><div class='row'>" %}
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

The cycle bit I have there works to separate every second element, but I want it to be every 4th. Without it, I get 4 elements per line. This is what I want. Basically, I'm trying to make a standard height per column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{% if forloop.counter0|divisibleby:4 %}
    <div class='col-sm-12'><hr/></div></div><div></div><div class='row'>
{% endif %}
```

More info about divisibleby: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#divisibleby

Answer (score 0):

You can pass more than two arguments to the cycle tag. For example:

```
{% cycle "" "" "" "<div..." %}
```

It might be tidier to use `divisibleby` as 1GDST suggests, I'm just adding this answer as an alternative.